# Simple navigation

Tags: typescript, angular8

I need to navigate to a url that looks like this:

`orders?id=99`

This is my code:

```
let id: number = 99;
this.router.navigate(['orders'], { queryParams: { id: id } });
```

I also tried this, with the same result:

```
this.router.navigate(['orders', { id: 99 } ]);
```

It just redirects to the root so probably my syntax is wrong, but I can't find a clear example online of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just did this, which feels like cheating but it works:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`/orders?id=${id}`);
```